# Where should the semi-colon that it is saying I need go?

Tags: c++

expected member name or ';' after declaration specifiers

This is the error I am getting and I am not sure where it wants me to put the semi-colon as I think I have placed them all correctly.
This is the section of the code where the error occurs.

```cpp
class Read : public Data {
    
public: {   
      
      float result_1 = sensor_stream1.get_data(&state);
      float result_2 = sensor_stream2.get_data(&state);
      float result_3 = sensor_stream3.get_data(&state);
      
      std::cout << result_1 << '\t';
      
    };
  };
```

On the bracket after the second public is where it says the error is.
The data class that this class is inheriting from doesn't show any errors whilst writing or when I have run the code.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Create a [mcve]

Comment: Is there supposed to be a function signature somewhere in there? You just have `public:` and then a block of code.

Comment: You appear to have provided a function body without a function.

Comment: What is this `public: {  `? Why `std::cout << result_1 << '\t';` in (seemingly) class scope? It must be in function scope. You cannot learn C++ by guessing. Consider learning C++ from [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: The error is a red herring. Compiler is too confused with syntax, so it proposes a semicolon, when in fact you are missing function syntax before a body.

Comment: The declaration specifier is `public:`. It is normally followed by a member declaration, but the syntax also allows a (meaningless) semicolon in many places, including there (`class A { public:;;;;};` is a valid nonsensical class definition). Being confused by your `{`, the compiler has no idea what you're trying to say and gives up at `{`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't put arbitrary code in a class definition. Only instance variable and function declarations belong in there. If you intend that the code be run during the constructor, make that explicit.

```
class Read : public Data {
public:
  Read() { 
  
    float result_1 = sensor_stream1.get_data(&state);
    float result_2 = sensor_stream2.get_data(&state);
    float result_3 = sensor_stream3.get_data(&state);
  
    std::cout << result_1 << '\t';
  
  }
};
```

Comment: I still question the purpose of this code with only setting local variables in the constructor.